# Listing BuiltInDocumentProperties leads to error

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to list all built in and custom document properties. I do this with the following code:

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub CheckDocumentCustomProperties()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Custom As Object
Dim Default As Object
Set Custom = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
Set Default = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties
       
'    Debug.Print "CustomDocumentProperties:"; vbNewLine
'
'    For i = 1 To Custom.Count
'             Debug.Print Custom.Item(i).Name + ": " + Custom.Item(i).Value
'             On Error Resume Next
'    Next
    
Debug.Print vbNewLine; "BuiltinDocumentProperties:"; vbNewLine
    
For i = 1 To Default.Count
    Debug.Print Default.Item(i).Name + " " + Default.Item(i).Value
Next
      
End Sub
```

My issue is that runtime error 13 pops up. Therefore, I commented out the custom properties, cause I thought there is an issue there. However, I still get the error.
So, I run the code as displayed once and with the following modification, commenting out the values:

```
For i = 1 To Default.Count
    Debug.Print Default.Item(i).Name '+ " " + Default.Item(i).Value
```

The result is the following:

```
BuiltinDocumentProperties:
    
Title Standard_Vorlage
Subject 
Author IMS Team
Keywords 
Comments 
Template Normal.dotm
Last author Hodzic Adis
Revision number 3
Application name Microsoft Office Word
    
BuiltinDocumentProperties:
    
Title
Subject
Author
Keywords
Comments
Template
Last author
Revision number
Application name
Last print date
Creation date
Last save time
Total editing time
Number of pages
Number of words
Number of characters
Security
Category
Format
Manager
Company
Number of bytes
Number of lines
Number of paragraphs
Number of slides
Number of notes
Number of hidden Slides
Number of multimedia clips
Hyperlink base
Number of characters (with spaces)
Content type
Content status
Language
Document version
```

By comparing, I notice that the `Last print date` is causing the first error. Unfortunately, I also don't know how to fix that or why that issue is occurring...

I also tried to convert my code into a string, but that was not the solution:

```
Debug.Print CStr(Default.Item(i).Name + " " + Default.Item(i).Value)
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.builtindocumentproperties?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158008296);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation (link in comments) says that calling Value() on a DocumentProperty that hasn't been set causes an error. There doesn't seem to be a way to test this before calling Value(), so you have to handle the error yourself. If you haven't printed the document, you won't have a Last Print Date for example.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CheckDocumentCustomProperties()

    Dim Default As Object
    Set Default = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties
        
    Debug.Print vbNewLine; "BuiltinDocumentProperties:"; vbNewLine

    Dim vProp As Variant
    Dim op As DocumentProperty

    On Error GoTo BadValue
    Dim strDbg As String

    For Each op In Default
        strDbg =  op.Name & "= "
        vProp = op.Value
        Debug.Print strDbg & vProp
    Next op
      
    Exit Sub

BadValue:
    vProp = "!Missing Value!"
    Resume Next
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain "Dim op As DocumentProperty"? I would expect a data type instead of "DocumentProperty"...

Comment: @Adis1102 - it is a data type. `op` is typed as a [`DocumentProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.documentproperty) object

Comment: Effectively DocumentProperty is a type (like Object). You could replace "Dim Default as Object", with "Dim Default as DocumentProperties". An Object is a collection of data and methods, and requires the "Set" keyword to assign it. eg ActiveDocument is a Document object. By defining a variable as a specific kind of object, VBA can tell you what methods it has, and what parameters they take. Look in the Tools / References menu in VBA. and you will see some libraries checked: they contain all the info that allows VBA to recognize DocumentProperty for example.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the value of the property when it has not been set.

As per documentation:

> If the container application doesn't define a value for one of the
> built-in document properties, reading the Value property for that
> document property causes an error.

[DocumentProperty.Value property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.documentproperty.value)

Therefore you need to check if the value is null before trying to read it.

```
With Default.Item(i)
    If Not IsNull(.Value) Then Debug.Print .Value Else Debug.Print "Empty"
End With
```

**Edit:**

As it turns out, there's a bit more to it than checking for null, but this can be easily overcome with a helper method to read the value.

```
Private Function ReadValue(prop As Object) As String
    
    Dim retValue As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    retValue = prop.Value
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then retValue = "Empty"
    
    ReadValue = retValue
End Function
```

Then just call the method to get its value (if any).

```
Dim prop As Object

For Each prop In ActiveDocument.BuiltinDocumentProperties
    Debug.Print prop.Name & ": " & ReadValue(prop)
Next

'Last print date: Empty
```

Comment: Did you try this? When I call IsNull() on the Value property, I still get an error, as per the documentation.

Comment: In the Debugger, you can see that the Value method call is failing, and that is raising the error. It is not that the returned value is the Variant Type VT_NULL. Perhaps this is because they don't want the caller to interpret NULL is some way (eg = 0), as the property value really is undefined.

Comment: FWIW, the error code is
E_FAIL Unspecified failure 0x80004005.Which is the developer's way of telling you not to trust whatever is in the returned parameter, as it is undefined.

Comment: @Adis1102 I suggested an answer that uses the less elegant VBA On Error as an alternative. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

See Astrid Zeelenberg's article on this [Word MVP Page](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/MixedDocProps.htm): [How to use a single VBA procedure to read or write both custom and built-in Document Properties](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/MixedDocProps.htm)

> When you work with Document Properties in code, most people end up
> with two functions >or subroutines, one to write built-in Document
> Properties and one for custom Document >Properties; because in each
> case the object used to refer to the Document Properties is >different
> – you have to use the CustomDocumentProperties and
> BuiltinDocumentProperties >collection as appropriate. But this can be
> very inconvenient. Writing Document Properties
>
> However, you can write a procedure which checks whether the property
> you want to write the value for is custom or built-in, and then uses
> the appropriate collection. (Note: If you are not familiar with
> calling subroutines with arguments, see: How to cut out repetition and
> write much less code, by using subroutines and functions that take
> arguments).
>
> This is how to do it:

```
Public Sub WriteProp(sPropName As String, sValue As String, _
      Optional lType As Long = msoPropertyTypeString)

'In the above declaration, "Optional lType As Long = msoPropertyTypeString" means
'that if the Document Property's Type is Text, we don't need to include the lType argument
'when we call the procedure; but if it's any other Prpperty Type (e.g. date) then we do

Dim bCustom As Boolean

  On Error GoTo ErrHandlerWriteProp

  'Try to write the value sValue to the custom documentproperties
  'If the customdocumentproperty does not exists, an error will occur
  'and the code in the errorhandler will run
  ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(sPropName).Value = sValue
  'Quit this routine
  Exit Sub

Proceed:
  'We know now that the property is not a builtin documentproperty,
  'but a custom documentproperty, so bCustom = True
  bCustom = True

Custom:
  'Try to set the value for the customproperty sPropName to sValue
  'An error will occur if the documentproperty doesn't exist yet
  'and the code in the errorhandler will take over
  ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties(sPropName).Value = sValue
  Exit Sub

AddProp:
  'We came here from the errorhandler, so know we know that
  'property sPropName is not a built-in property and that there's
  'no custom property with this name
  'Add it
  On Error Resume Next
  ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:=sPropName, _
    LinkToContent:=False, Type:=lType, Value:=sValue

  If Err Then
    'If we still get an error, the value isn't valid for the Property Type
    'e,g an invalid date was used
    Debug.Print "The Property " & Chr(34) & _
     sPropName & Chr(34) & " couldn't be written, because " & _
     Chr(34) & sValue & Chr(34) & _
     " is not a valid value for the property type"
  End If

  Exit Sub

ErrHandlerWriteProp:
  Select Case Err
    Case Else
   'Clear the error
   Err.Clear
   'bCustom is a boolean variable, if the code jumps to this
   'errorhandler for the first time, the value for bCustom is False
   If Not bCustom Then
     'Continue with the code after the label Proceed
     Resume Proceed
   Else
     'The errorhandler was executed before because the value for
     'the variable bCustom is True, therefor we know that the
     'customdocumentproperty did not exist yet, jump to AddProp,
     'where the property will be made
     Resume AddProp
   End If
  End Select

End Sub
```

> We could call the above procedure like this:

```
Sub Test()
  'Author is a built-in property
  Call WriteProp(sPropName:="Author", sValue:="William Shakespeare")

  'Date Updated is a custom document property
  Call WriteProp(sPropName:="Date Updated", sValue:="11 Mar 2001", _
    lType:=msoPropertyTypeDate)
End Sub
```

> **Reading Document Properties**
>
> The same principle can be used when reading Document Properties:

```
Function ReadProp(sPropName As String) As Variant

Dim bCustom As Boolean
Dim sValue As String

  On Error GoTo ErrHandlerReadProp
  'Try the built-in properties first
  'An error will occur if the property doesn't exist
  sValue = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(sPropName).Value
  ReadProp = sValue
  Exit Function

ContinueCustom:
  bCustom = True

Custom:
  sValue = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties(sPropName).Value
  ReadProp = sValue
  Exit Function

ErrHandlerReadProp:
  Err.Clear
  'The boolean bCustom has the value False, if this is the first
  'time that the errorhandler is runned
  If Not bCustom Then
    'Continue to see if the property is a custom documentproperty
    Resume ContinueCustom
  Else
    'The property wasn't found, return an empty string
    ReadProp = ""
    Exit Function
  End If

End Function
```

> We could call the function like this:

```
Sub Test()

Dim PropVal As String
 
  PropVal = ReadProp("Author")
  Debug.Print PropVal

  PropVal = ReadProp("Date Completed")
  Debug.Print PropVal

End Sub
```

Although old, this code still works as far as I know. I have used it.

Comment: All code is quoted from the article. I saw no way to post code within a blockquote.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your inpu community!
Here is my code that I use which is actually the solution from @DS_London.
I do have something to point out at the end...

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyWorkbookProperties()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Custom As Object
Set Custom = ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties
Dim Default As DocumentProperties
Set Default = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties

Dim Name As Variant
Dim Value As Variant
Dim cp As CustomProperty
Dim dp As DocumentProperty


On Error GoTo BadValue

Debug.Print vbNewLine; "Built in Document Properties"; vbNewLine

'For Each dp In Default
    'Name = dp.Name & ": "
    'Value = dp.Value
    'Debug.Print Name + Value
'Next

For i = 1 To Default.Count
    Name = Default.Item(i).Name & ": "
    Value = Default.Item(i).Value
    Debug.Print Name + Value
Next


Debug.Print vbNewLine; "Custom Document Properties"; vbNewLine

'For Each cp In Custom
     'Name = cp.Name & ": "
     'Value = cp.Value
     'Debug.Print Name + Value
'Next

For i = 1 To Custom.Count
    Name = Custom.Item(i).Name & ": "
    Value = Custom.Item(i).Value
    Debug.Print Name + Value
Next

BadValue:
Value = "Bad Value"
Resume Next
             
    
End Sub
```

In my question, I did mention the CustomProperties. In case you are not aware of the following two loops are NOT the same. I do use the one that is not commented out of course

```
  'For Each cp In Custom
        'Name = cp.Name & ": "
        'Value = cp.Value
        'Debug.Print Name + Value
  'Next
    
  For i = 1 To Custom.Count
        Name = Custom.Item(i).Name & ": "
        Value = Custom.Item(i).Value
        Debug.Print Name + Value
  Next
```

As I was still missing some values, I had to add the `ContentTypeProperties`. Codewise I added the following:

```
Debug.Print vbNewLine; "Content Type Properties"; vbNewLine

Dim Content As Object
Set Content = ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties

For i = 1 To Content.Count
    Name = Content.Item(i).Name & ": "
    Value = Content.Item(i).Value
    Debug.Print Name + Value
Next
```